# Convert planar x/y to lat/long

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Im trying to write a program that takes new york city x/y coords and turns them into lat/lng decimal points. Im new to planar/globe mapping. Ive included the constants that NYC has provided on their website. Also if there is a good article on how to do this I would love to learn! Below is the program I have written along with commented output at the bottom and also what the ideal values should be. Im kinda just stumbling in the dark on this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from math import *

"""
Supplied by NYC
Lambert Conformal Conic:

    Standard Parallel: 40.666667
    Standard Parallel: 41.033333
    Longitude of Central Meridian: -74.000000
    Latitude of Projection Origin: 40.166667
    False Easting: 984250.000000
    False Northing: 0.000000

"""

x = 981106                      #nyc x coord
y = 195544                      #nyc y coord
a = 6378137                     #' major radius of ellipsoid, map units (NAD 83)
e = 0.08181922146               #' eccentricity of ellipsoid (NAD 83)
angRad = pi/180                 #' number of radians in a degree
pi4 = pi/4                      #' Pi / 4

p0 = 40.166667 * angRad        #' latitude of origin
p1 = 40.666667 * angRad        #' latitude of first standard parallel
p2 = 41.033333 * angRad        #' latitude of second standard parallel
m0 = -74.000000 * angRad       #' central meridian
x0 = 984250.000000             #' False easting of central meridian, map units

m1 = cos(p1) / sqrt(1 - ((e ** 2) * sin(p1) ** 2))
m2 = cos(p2) / sqrt(1 - ((e ** 2) * sin(p2) ** 2))
t0 = tan(pi4 - (p0 / 2))
t1 = tan(pi4 - (p1 / 2))
t2 = tan(pi4 - (p2 / 2))
t0 = t0 / (((1 - (e * (sin(p0)))) / (1 + (e * (sin(p0)))))**(e / 2))
t1 = t1 / (((1 - (e * (sin(p1)))) / (1 + (e * (sin(p1)))))**(e / 2))
t2 = t2 / (((1 - (e * (sin(p2)))) / (1 + (e * (sin(p2)))))**(e / 2))
n = log(m1 / m2) / log(t1 / t2)
f = m1 / (n * (t1 ** n))
rho0 = a * f * (t0 ** n)

x = x - x0
pi2 = pi4 * 2
rho = sqrt((x ** 2) + ((rho0 - y) ** 2))
theta = atan(x / (rho0 - y))
t = (rho / (a * f)) ** (1 / n)
lon = (theta / n) + m0
x = x + x0

lat0 = pi2 - (2 * atan(t))

part1 = (1 - (e * sin(lat0))) / (1 + (e * sin(lat0)))
lat1 = pi2 - (2 * atan(t * (part1 ** (e / 2))))
while abs(lat1 - lat0) < 0.000000002:
    lat0 = lat1
    part1 = (1 - (e * sin(lat0))) / (1 + (e * sin(lat0)))
    lat1 = pi2 - (2 * atan(t * (part1 ^ (e / 2))))

lat = lat1 / angRad
lon = lon / angRad

print lat,lon
#output : 41.9266666432 -74.0378981653
#should be 40.703778, -74.011829
```

Im pretty stuck, I have a ton of these that need geo-coded
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection could get you started?

Comment: More details about the projection used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection

Comment: Just read that article and started implementing the formula then I realized that I am doing an ellipsoidal transformation and that formula isn't there all it says is: Formulæ for ellipsoidal datums are more involved.

Comment: Your code states that this is a conic projection, not ellipsoidal...

Comment: hmm good catch, didnt even see that, thats probably why im just a hair off. Im calculating for the eccentricity of ellipsoid when the data is conic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One word answer: [pyproj](http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/)

```
>>> from pyproj import Proj
>>> pnyc = Proj(
...     proj='lcc',
...     datum='NAD83',
...     lat_1=40.666667,
...     lat_2=41.033333,
...     lat_0=40.166667,
...     lon_0=-74.0,
...     x_0=984250.0,
...     y_0=0.0)
>>> x = [981106.0]
>>> y = [195544.0]
>>> lon, lat = pnyc(x, y, inverse=True)
>>> lon, lat
([-74.037898165369015], [41.927378144152335])
```

Comment: This looks awesome! but still not the accuracy that I need, is that just a limitation of the data being in x,y? Actually that just outputs the results I already have :S

Comment: also after playing around with this shouldn't the longitude -74

Comment: I geocoded using Google from the address I have. This should end up somewhere in lower Manhattan. Here is a link to the map description http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/meta_mappluto.shtml#Spatial_Reference_Information

Comment: never mind, the address is 99 BROAD STREET in Manhattan, even with the -74 change im still landing in upstate kinda by Poughkeepsie. Unless this data that I got from nyc is bad.

Comment: K now I really figured it out. The nyc data is in feet. :(

Comment: i wondered about that, but doesn't it all come out in the wash if the elliptic major axis is in feet too?

Comment: Yup, there a few meters off from the Google geo-code but it just looks like the city of New York chose the corner of the building instead of the middle. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you explain what are lat1 and lat0 here?

Answer (score 1):

These formulas should help you out:

http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/conversion-coordinates/projection-conversions/lambert-conformal-conic#lbl3

Answer (score 0):

owww.  you'd be better using a library for this.  a little searching suggests that should be [the python interface to gdal](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython)

[this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/how-should-i-use-gdal-to-perform-a-transformation) uses gdal, but not via the python api (they just call gdal via a command line from within python), but might help.

you might be best asking at [gis stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) for more info.

i'm unclear where you got the code above from.  if you link to it i/someone could check for obvious implementation errors.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone! I hacked up some code I found at the Montana State GIS repo. It was written in asp/vb heres the link. Its pretty much identical to my code. I am going to check out this library though. http://nris.mt.gov/gis/projection/stategeo_asp.txt Also I do have the addresses for these buildings which is how I got the correct geocode. I just have waaaaaaaaaaaay to many of these to use a geocoding service.

Comment: @arboc7 caught the fact that my data is conical but this program is for an ellipsoid. Which I think is why I am getting close answers but not correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to work through all the math, you could just pick a grid over your map surface and find out the lat/long of those grid points, then use interpolation to do the conversion. Depending on the linearity of the projection it might not take many points to get good accuracy.